# Event on Item Marked as Read in Outlook - Delphi COM Add-in

Tags: delphi, events, com, outlook, outlook-object-model

I have a Delphi COM Add-in for Outlook (2000-2007) and am trying to find a way to register an event when an MailItem in Outlook is marked as read.  I want to add an additional property to the item as/just after it is marked as read.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this using the Outlook Object Model?  I am also using Add-In-Express components to help get to additional properties events.

Answer (score 2):

There are two MailItem events you could use for this:

- The "Read" even will be called.
- The PropertyChange event will be called with a parameter of "UnRead". However, this particular event will also be called when the MailItem is marked as "read" again.

Comment: Is there a way to have these events fire reliably?  From my testing (which could be failing), they seem to fire at odd times and you don't always get Read firing.